# Go binary failed to run in openshift

Tags: linux, go, openshift

I have developed a basic go rest webservice in go 1.2. It is working as expected in my local linux box. But when I scp'ed the generated binary to openshift and try to execute, it terminates instantaneously without listening to the port. Here is the application code : https://gist.github.com/anidotnet/9720936

I tried with both binary compiled at openshift server and binary compiled at my local linux box, but the result is same. Tried executing it using

> nohup ./app $

but it still terminates. No panic log is there as well. What is going wrong here? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not a Go expert, but here are some things to check in your program:

Make sure that you are binding to port 8080 to serve your application from
Make sure that you are binding to your openshift ip address (not 127.0.0.1, localhost, or 0.0.0.0 which are usually the defaults)

Here is an OpenShift Go Cartridge that you can try (check out the code in the template directory) for hints on how to bind correctly: https://github.com/smarterclayton/openshift-go-cart

The environment variables you need can be found by sshing into your gear and running the following commands:
env | grep IP
env | grep PORT

These will be named according to the type of web cartridge you have installed.

Comment: Ahh!! There it is..I was binding the app at localhost ip..Thanks a million. Now it is kicking at openshift..:)